# Positioning image next to centered text

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble positioning my image next to my `h1`. The `h1` is centered, and I would like to have my image placed on the right side of it. However, The position of the `h1` may not be changed (thus, the image may not affect the position of the `h1`).

Relevant code I have so far:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header </h1><img src="pencil.jpg" alt="">
</div>



h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

This code doesn't work at all; the image appears on the left side of the web page and is not being positioned relative to the `h1` as I would like to.

I tried fixing this by putting the image into the `h1` (to make it it's parent element), but by doing this the position of the `h1` element changes (because the reserved space for the image is still preserved in the `h1` element).

I hope someone can help me.
Kind regards,
Nick

Comment: That's because you're using a block level tag with another block level tag. Set your h1 to a specific width and then try using  floats. Check out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp for  more info pertaining to inline VS. block level elements. :)

Comment: Try using `display:inline;` or floats on your elements.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using a block level tag with another block level tag.

Check out [W3 Schools](http://w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) for more info pertaining to inline VS. block level elements. :)

And if you want a more direct example using your code, here is a [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wgynjjr4/4/) This has it so the text is centered and the image is next to it, centered as well.

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This works well, except for one thing: however the position of the image has been changed, the reserved space for the image is still preserved in the h1 element. This makes the h1 element bigger, and because it is center aligned, the text inside the h1 element will move to the left (because the image takes up some space on the right).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to give `#header` `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to the img:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -80px;
    left: 60%;
}
#header {
    position: relative;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5m3s0bno/4/)

Comment: This works well, until the brower window is resized. The image's position is now relative to the header, wich makes that the distance between the image and header varies depending on the window width. I'd like the image to have a standard position relative to the h1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot absolutely position elements with position relative. You should use position absolute.

This wont resize very well though. Hope it helps. :)

```
img {
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 0;
width: 100px;
```

}

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wdgb753e/)

Comment: Same problem as another content made here: With this solution, the image's position varies depending on the with of the browser window. I'd like the image to be placed right next to the h1, wich has a standard position (center aligned).

Comment: Added a new answer with 2 possible solutions. :) Hope they help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want them right next to eachother...

Wrap the header text in a span.

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>
        <span>Header</span>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300" alt="" />
    </h1>
</div>
```

Set both the span and the image to display: inline-block;

```
h1 span, h1 img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want the text dead center then add some padding to the left, equal to the width of the image.

```
h1 span {
    padding-left: 36px;
}

h1 img {
    width: 36px;
}
```

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/wdgb753e/7/)

**Alternatively**

Put the image inside the span

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>
        <span>
            Header
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300" alt="" />
        </span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

And set it to position absolute, so it hangs out the right hand side.

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 span {
    position: relative;
}

h1 img {
    position: absolute;
    right: -36px;
    width: 36px;
}
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wdgb753e/6/)

Neither are perfect solutions, but hopefully one will be right for you. :)